# Swift 'Fast' optimization level causes crash from underretaining

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I wrote a String extension function in Swift that takes in a Protocol type. It runs a few checks based on the parameter, and throws errors if the base object does not meet the requirements:

```
func satisfiesComplexityRequirements(setForthBy policy: SCPasswordComplexity) throws
{
    guard isAtLeastThisLong(policy.minLength()) else
    {
        throw SCPolicyPasswordComplexityError.TooShort
    }

    let maxLen = policy.maxLength()
    if maxLen > 0
    {
        guard isNoLongerThan(maxLen) else
        {
            throw SCPolicyPasswordComplexityError.TooLong
        }
    }

    guard doesNotExceedThisNumberOfRepeatedCharacters(policy.maxRepeats()) else
    {
        throw SCPolicyPasswordComplexityError.TooManyRepeatingCharacters
    }
}
```

Running this code with (Swift) optimization level 'Fast' shows the `SCPasswordComplexity` object not getting retained, but it does get released. This net loss in retain count causes the object to be deallocated (prematurely), leading to an eventual crash:

[Zombies Instrument catching reference to prematurely released object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmVW0.png)

Why is the `SCPasswordComplexity` object not getting retained inside the function? The function clearly references it. I have also noticed that the app does not crash when it runs the first `throw` statement, but it crashes when it runs the other two `throw` statements.